# Creating a complex pivot table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and T-SQL. These are abbreviated examples.

My table/view has the following fields

```
Table/View
    ReportID,   
    UnitName,
    UnitID,
    CaseDefinitionID,
    CaseDefinition,
    DateOfDelivery,
    YEAR(DateOfDelivery) AS [Year],
    MONTH(DateOfDelivery) AS [Month],
    DATENAME(m,DateOfDelivery) AS [Month name]
```

and my target report is:

```
Unit    |   Case type 1|    Case type 2|    Case total|
Unit A  |            36|             40|            76|

    2013|            20|             18|            38|
     Jan|            10|
     Feb|            10|

    2014|            16|
     Mar|             8|
     Dec|             8|

Unit B  |            12|
    2013|            12|
     Jan|             6|
     May|             6|

Grand total|         48|
```

The month rows can be empty, NULL content is fine. The example report is incomplete to aid clarity.

Progress so far is the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        PCT.[Year],
        PCT.UnitName AS [Unit],
        PCT.UnitID,
        PCT.CaseDefinition AS [Case definition]

    FROM
        PivotBase AS PCT            
) AS P1

PIVOT
(
    COUNT(UnitID)
    FOR [Case definition] IN ([Case type 1],[Case type 2])
) AS P2
```

This produces the following table

```
Year|Unit   |Case type 1|Case type 2|
2013|Unit A |       20  |         18|
2014|Unit A |       16  |         22|
2013|Unit B |       6   |          8|
2014|Unit B |       6   |          8|
```

There is no need for dynamic SQL

My reading so far has covered many options but I still have no idea where to go next. How do I produce the required report.

Comment: I think you should just output the normalized form and rely on Excel to do the pivoting. Is there a reason you *have* to do it in SQL?

Comment: @ZoffDino Excel is not an option sadly; this is for a web site. I could also write it in C# but again not a real option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get there by pivoting on Month and Year and then using WITH ROLLUP

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   (SELECT Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, PCT.dateofdelivery), 0 
                        ) 
                        MonthYear, 
                        PCT.unitid, 
                        PCT.unitname 
                        AS 
                        [Unit], 
                        PCT.casedefinition 
                        AS 
                                [Case definition] 
                 FROM   pivotbase AS PCT) AS P1 
                PIVOT ( Count(unitid) 
                      FOR [case definition] IN ([Case type 1], 
                                                [Case type 2]) ) AS p2), 
     rollup 
     AS (SELECT Month(monthyear)           Month, 
                unit                       unitX, 
                Year(monthyear)            Year, 
                Sum([case type 1])         [case type 1], 
                Sum([case type 2])         [case type 2], 
                Grouping(unit)             GUnit, 
                Grouping(Month(monthyear)) gm, 
                Grouping(Year(monthyear))  gy 
         FROM   data 
         GROUP  BY unit, 
                   Year(monthyear), 
                   Month(monthyear) WITH rollup) 
SELECT COALESCE(Cast(month AS VARCHAR), Cast(year AS VARCHAR), unitx, 
       'Grand Total') 
       Unit, 
       [case type 1], 
       [case type 2] 
FROM   rollup 
ORDER  BY gunit, 
          unitx, 
          year, 
          gm DESC, 
          month
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/280b5/54)

Answer (score 2):

It's doable with some fancy rollup ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97eab8/2/0))

```
;WITH
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT      UnitName,
                    [Year],
                    [Month],
                    CaseDefinition,
                    GROUPING_ID(UnitName,[Year],[Month],CaseDefinition) 
                                        AS GroupingID,
                    CASE GROUPING_ID(CaseDefinition,UnitName,[Year],[Month])
                        WHEN 0 THEN UnitName + '-' + CAST(Year AS varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Month] AS varchar(10)),2)
                        WHEN 1 THEN UnitName + '-' + CAST(Year AS varchar(4))
                        WHEN 3 THEN UnitName
                        WHEN 7 THEN 'zzz'  -- So that grand total appears at the bottom
                        ELSE NULL
                    END                 AS GroupingLevel,
                    CASE GROUPING_ID(CaseDefinition,UnitName,[Year],[Month])
                        WHEN 0 THEN '    ' + CASE [Month]
                                                WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan'
                                                WHEN 2 THEN 'Feb'
                                                WHEN 3 THEN 'Mar'
                                                WHEN 4 THEN 'Apr'
                                                WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
                                                WHEN 6 THEN 'Jun'
                                                WHEN 7 THEN 'Jul'
                                                WHEN 8 THEN 'Aug'
                                                WHEN 9 THEN 'Sep'
                                                WHEN 10 THEN 'Oct'
                                                WHEN 11 THEN 'Nov'
                                                WHEN 12 THEN 'Dec'
                                             END
                        WHEN 1 THEN '  '   + CAST([Year] AS varchar(4))
                        WHEN 3 THEN UnitName
                        WHEN 7 THEN 'Grand Total'
                    END                 AS DisplayName,
                    COUNT(UnitID)       AS UnitCount
        FROM        PivotBase
        GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS(
                        (CaseDefinition),
                        (UnitName,CaseDefinition),
                        (UnitName,[Year],[CaseDefinition]),
                        (UnitName,[Year],[Month],CaseDefinition)
                    )
    )

SELECT      pvt.GroupingLevel,
            pvt.DisplayName,
            pvt.[Case Type 1],
            pvt.[Case Type 2],
            ISNULL(pvt.[Case Type 1],0) + ISNULL(pvt.[Case Type 2],0) AS [Case Total]
FROM        CTE1
PIVOT       (
                SUM(UnitCount) FOR CaseDefinition IN ([Case Type 1],[Case Type 2])
            ) pvt
ORDER BY    GroupingLevel
```

**Explanation:**

1. `GROUPING SET( (set1), (set2), (set3) )` defines the roll up level. You will get a count of `UnitID` for each unique combination *inside* `set1`, then `set2`, then `set3`
2. `GROUPING_ID` is the most obscure function in here. Think of it as a bit mask. If a column is aggregated, its bit value is set to 1. For example: `GROUPING_ID(field3, field2, field1, field0)`. If all 4 are not aggregated, the bit mask is `0000 = 0`. If `field0` is aggregated away, the returned value is `0001 = 1`, and so on.

You can replace the last SELECT with `SELECT * FROM CTE1` to see the inner working of the query.

Comment: I went with a Rollup after the pivot instead of before but nice use of GROUPING_ID